# PHP Uploading file unsuccessful

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to my local server, but it keeps being unsuccessful.

All my files are inside /var/www/html/ 
However I made a folder called uploads in the html folder, and I changed its permissions to 777 (what I took on average from searching was the best for my needs)

this is my code: 
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
echo "Target File: " . $target_file . "<br />";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).  " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Clue: Look at your input name and the other two in the `$_FILES` arrays. Look at those very carefully. You will find your own answer and would have performed your first debugging operation. ;-)

Comment: aside : there is very rarely any reason to ever `777`

Comment: @CD001 Probably thinking that if folder was set to 755 and that didn't work, then 777 "must" work then.

Comment: and why do you use a hidden field to pass MAX_FILE_SIZE ?

Comment: There's good documentation on handling uploads in the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) but please for the love of all things holy be careful or you'll get owned by uploaded scripts. Note that mod_php w/AddHandler considers "lol.php.jpg" to be PHP, so don't just validate a file based on last extension. A good idea is to never allow the user to choose the filename in the first place; black-listing "dangerous" patterns is brittle.

Comment: where is target path

Comment: Do visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php plus, as detailer caught the unassigned variable for the target path; good catch @detailer OP has enough to get the code going.

Comment: i iam sure luna-games copied the code from somewhere

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I was hoping their wouldn't be an error like this in there. Thanks for noticing! But even with the function getting the right directory it's still spitting out it was unsuccessful.

Comment: @detailer Aye! It's what I've managed to pieced together from a bunch of different tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Input file is

`<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />`

so change `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` to `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']`

`$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']` **Must** have the value of `Name` attribute of your file field

Comment: Cheers for answering! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**upload.php**

```
if(isset($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"]) && ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < 5000000)){
      $sourcePath = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
      $file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
      $targetPath = "/uploads/".$file;
      if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)){
      echo "The file: ".$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']." has been uploaded";
   }else{
      echo "Looks like it failed.";
   }
}else{
   echo "You forgot to select a file, or the file size is too large.";
}
```

So what this does is checks if a file exists and checks if it's smaller than 5MB. If so it moves on to the upload part.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it just doesn't seem to work. It's just failing every time, regardless of the code

Comment: What kind of server are you running? @luna-games

Comment: @jasson-basset Thanks for the reply, I'm running a local apache server

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the variable

```
$target_path
```

you meant but not used

```
$target_file
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! A tad embarrassing for that to be there. However i'm still getting the same unsuccessful upload

Comment: You are wrong.

OP is using wrong Input Field name inside `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']`

See my answer